# overwrite php method inside the class, will it has any impact on original php method?

Tags: php, oop

```
interface StorageInterface
{
    public function isset($index);
    public function set($index, $value);
    public function unset($index);
}
```

Hi, I have a question regarding overwrite the php original method into my own class method. Will it has any impact on orignal php method? 
and does it consider a good practice or bad?

Or it is better to provide the similar method name. 
so here is the actual implementation of the method (isset) and (unset) in StorageSession class

```
public function isset($index)
{
   return isset($_SESSION[$this->product][$index]);
}

public function unset($index)
{
   unset($_SESSION[$this->product][$index]);
}
```

So that when i create my Product class. 
i can implement something like this

```
public function __construct(SessionStorage $storage);

public function hasProduct($product)
{
    $this->storage->isset($product->id);
}

public function removeProduct($product)
{
   $this->storage->unset($product->id);
}
```

so the question is, should I name the `isset() and unset()` method, with some other similar name like, `check(), has(), remove(), delete()` . Or it is okay to name it `isset() and unset()`

Comment: You need to `return` the isset.

Answer (score 0):

isset and unset are keywords. Since PHP 7 they can be used as method names, but not in PHP 5.

Though, what's wrong with using normal names like check?

Comment: I would like to keep methods consistency, while having too many different named method with similar functionality will always confuse me.

Comment: Yes, I do think about giving it a diff name like check(), remove(). But I always end up that i need to go back to definition to refer what the method does. That's why I would prefer just to name the method name to keyword  name.